# Не могу найти удалённый вопрос через инструменты модератора

Tags: поддержка, удаление-вопросов

Почему-то не удаётся увидеть [недавно удалённый вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4961/176217) через [инструменты модератора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools).

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Возможно, потому, что автор сам его удалил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin возможно, но это же не значит, что сообщество должно потерять такой вопрос из вида вовсе только лишь по прихоти автора.

Comment: вы же сами отправили автора на английскую мету )

Comment: @NickVolynkin о других забочусь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На другом сайте недавно обсуждали [то же самое](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439). Вердикт: удаленные самостоятельно сообщения не показываются через страницу инструментов модератора 10k. То есть, [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be).

Попутно на MSE создан [вопрос с предложением](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292531/339911) разрешить отображение самоудаленных сообщений.